# dplyr manipulation rowwise grouping mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data sets

```
x <- data.frame(Postcode = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), 
                Latitude = c(3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.3, 3.4, 3.4),
                Longitude = c(100, 101, 102, 102, 103, 104),
                Exposure = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))
```

I am trying to manipulate the data inside x becomes

```
x <- data.frame(Postcode = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), 
                Latitude = c(3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.3, 3.4, 3.4),
                Longitude = c(100, 101, 102, 102, 103, 104),
                Exposure = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
                coords = c("3.1, 100", "3.2, 101", "3.3, 102", "3.3, 102",
                           "3.4, 103", "3.4, 104"),
                postcode = c("1", "2", "3,4", "3,4", "5", "6"),
                exposure = c(1, 2, 7, 7, 5, 6))
```

The new column `postcode` will paste together the `Postcode` that has the same `Latitude` and `Longitude`. `coords` will paste the `Latitude` and `Longitude`, while `exposure` will sum the `Exposure` that has the same `coords`, i.e., the same `Latitude` and `Longitude`.

I could accomplish this by using `dplyr` package and `for` loop

```
x <- mutate(x, coords = paste(Latitude, Longitude, sep = ", "))
x <- cbind(x, postcode = rep(0, nrow(x)), exposure = rep(0, nrow(x)))
for(i in unique(x$coords)){
  x$postcode[x$coords == i] <- paste(x$Postcode[x$coords == i], collapse = ", ")
  x$exposure[x$coords == i] <- sum(x$Exposure[x$coords == i])
}
```

How could I accomplish this by only using `dplyr` package only, without using `for` loop? or maybe other approach which is more efficient than using `for` loop because my actual data sets are quite large

Comment: The second dataset have unequal number of elements.  Please update it

Comment: @akrun I have edited it. Thanks for the notif

Comment: It's going to get closed if you don't fix: Error in data.frame(Postcode = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), Latitude = c(3.1,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 7, 6

Comment: @hrbrmstr sorry, ive fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do it with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
x %>% 
     group_by(coords = paste(Latitude, Longitude, sep = ", ")) %>% 
     mutate(postcode = toString(Postcode), exposure = sum(Exposure))

# Source: local data frame [6 x 7]
# Groups: coords [5]
# 
#   Postcode Latitude Longitude Exposure   coords postcode exposure
#      <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>    <chr>    <chr>    <dbl>
# 1        1      3.1       100        1 3.1, 100        1        1
# 2        2      3.2       101        2 3.2, 101        2        2
# 3        3      3.3       102        3 3.3, 102     3, 4        7
# 4        4      3.3       102        4 3.3, 102     3, 4        7
# 5        5      3.4       103        5 3.4, 103        5        5
# 6        6      3.4       104        6 3.4, 104        6        6
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your solution. My data is actually stored in a spatialpointsdataframe object. I thought I could manipulate it using this method, i just realize that I could not use group_by to the data in the spatialpointsdataframe object. Any suggestion?

Comment: I thought I could extract the data from the sp object first and then apply the dplyr, but i noticed that it changed the object so I could not store it back to the sp object

Comment: Anyway thanks. I just know that you could use group_by in that way

Comment: I don't know much about sp data frame either. Can't give more useful information on that topic.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)  # unite() was used to join Lat, Lon

x %>% unite(coords, Latitude, Longitude, sep = ",", remove = FALSE) %>% 
  group_by(coords) %>% mutate(exposure = sum(Postcode), postcode = toString(Postcode))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your solution. My data is actually stored in a spatialpointsdataframe object. I thought I could manipulate it using this method, i just realize that I could not use group_by to the data in the spatialpointsdataframe object. Any suggestion?

Comment: I thought I could extract the data from the sp object first and then apply the dplyr, but i noticed that it changed the object so I could not store it back to the sp object

Comment: actualy I have not much worked on `sp` objects. could you share mre details on hwat you are facing

Answer (score 1):

We can do this with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(x)[, coords := paste(Latitude, Longitude, sep="," )
  ][, c("exposure", "postcode") :=.(sum(Postcode), toString(Postcode)), coords]
x
#   Postcode Latitude Longitude Exposure  coords exposure postcode
#1:        1      3.1       100        1 3.1,100        1        1
#2:        2      3.2       101        2 3.2,101        2        2
#3:        3      3.3       102        3 3.3,102        7     3, 4
#4:        4      3.3       102        4 3.3,102        7     3, 4
#5:        5      3.4       103        5 3.4,103        5        5
#6:        6      3.4       104        6 3.4,104        6        6
```